Which is difference between two different imports?
I created a new project and there is some differences on importing on gradle files, I don't understand why its different from other projects that I have, is this wrong, can somebody tell me the difference, and how to make it same as other projects
The projects that I worked before:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
} 
...
dependencies {
    def daggerVersion = '2.21'
    def camerax_version = "1.2.0" //should update to release version in the future updates

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.6.1"

and here is the new project that i created:
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("kotlin-android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs")
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")



The new one is using the Kotlin DSL and the old one the Gradle DSL. Same fundamental functionality, same underlying build system, different details and syntax.

This question is similar to: Kotlin Android different (Module:App) build.gradle structures makes tutorials hard to follow. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Is there a way to change the configuration build language after creating the project?

While creating your new project in Android Studio just change the Build configuration language from Kotlin DSL to Groovy DSL, But Kotlin DSL will make faster builds compared to Groovy and Kotlin DSL recommended
